# Collecting names/ids of failing items in Camel

Tags: scala, apache-camel

I would like to implement an aggregator-splitter pattern using Camel where I process a list of files. `removeOnFailure(true)` would help remove files that would cause/trigger a failure from the list and the process will complete successfully as shown in the code below.

```
def files(exchange: Exchange): java.util.Iterator[Path]
def fileProcessor(exchange: Exchange): Unit

from(aDirectEndpoint) ==> {
    aggregate(
      split(files _)
        .streaming
        .parallelProcessing
        .idempotentConsumer(_.in)
        .eager(true)
        .skipDuplicate(true)
        .repository(aRepository)
        .removeOnFailure(true)
        .process(fileProcessor _),
      new GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy
    )
    .completionTimeout(completionTimeoutMillis)
    .process(jobProcessor)
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to collect those failing files using Camel API?

Comment: How about collecting all files names in set before the `removeOnFailure` step, then removing them after that step? That should leave you with the failed files in the set after you are done. You can carry the set as an exchange property.

Comment: Thanks, @Ralf. I'm trying to do exactly that but I'm not sure how to use exchange properties properly. Care to give a code example?

Comment: Check the [API doc](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/Exchange.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)).